# Select or highlight points on a Plotly heatmap

Tags: javascript, plotly, heatmap, plotly.js

Let's say we have a heatmap:

```js
const z = Array.from({length: 250}, () => Array.from({length: 500}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)));
Plotly.newPlot('plot',  [{z: z, type: 'heatmap'}]);
document.getElementById("go").onclick = () => { alert(); }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.26.0.min.js"></script>
<button id="go">Click to focus the pixels > 5</button>
<div id="plot"></div>
```

Let's say we have a `threshold = 5`.

How to empahsize/highlight pixels that are above the threshold?
Or maybe it's easier to make transparent or grey the pixels which are *below* the threshold.

The goal is to visually put the focus on the pixels above the threshold.

**How to do this with Plotly.js?**

Comment: Do you have a min/max value for pixels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can define a discrete value range for pixels (ex. min 0 and max 10), then you can define your `threshold` as a percentage value and use it to define a custom `colorscale`.

```js
const min = 0;
const max = 10;

const z = Array.from({length: 100}, () => Array.from({length: 100}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * max)));

const threshold = 5; // value included in the highlighted range
const breakpoint = threshold / max; // (percentage from 0.0 to 1.0)

const colorscaleValue = [
  [0.0, 'white'],
  [breakpoint, 'white'],
  [breakpoint, 'red'],
  [1, 'red']
];


Plotly.newPlot('plot',  [{z: z, type: 'heatmap', colorscale: colorscaleValue}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.26.0.min.js"></script>
<div id="plot"></div>
```

As you can see, all values in the first half of the range (50%, 0 to 5 pixels excluded) will be shown in white while values above the 50% (5 to 10, 5 included) will be shown in red. In my example i'm using just two colors to define values above and below your threshold. If you want to use a different colorscale, you can try this:

```js
const min = 0;
const max = 10;

const z = Array.from({length: 250}, () => Array.from({length: 500}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)));


const threshold = 5; // value included in the highlighted range
const breakpoint = threshold / max; // (percentage from 0.0 to 1.0)

const colorscaleValue = [
  [0.0, 'rgba(169,169,169,0.5)'],
  [breakpoint, 'rgba(169,169,169,0.5)'],
  [breakpoint, 'rgb(220,170,132)'],
  [1, 'rgb(178,10,28)'],
];


Plotly.newPlot('plot',  [{z: z, type: 'heatmap', colorscale: colorscaleValue}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.26.0.min.js"></script>
<div id="plot"></div>
```

You can of course set as many "breakpoints" as you wish in your `colorscale`, remember only that values goes from `0.0` to `1.0` and they represent the value range in percentage.

Comment: Thanks! Can we keep the original colorscale (example: 0=blue to 10=red) like in my question, and just modify the [0, 5] range to put it as uniformly transparent grey? The [5, 10] range would be unmodified. Do you see how to do this?

Comment: I modified the second snippet. Now 0-4 is grey and 5-10 red like original example. Does it help?

Comment: Yes it seems to work @AlbertoFecchi! I modified the snippet to be closer to the original question. Also I wonder how it would work if we have a more complex colorscale, like jet https://chart-studio.plotly.com/~nup/14/heatmap-with-jet-color-scale.embed. Do you have any idea?

Comment: The main idea is just to have a "percentage scale", so you can create your custom `colorscale`. You can add as many values as you wish from 0.0 to 1.0 and assign a different color in each step. With a bit of calculation (ex. If you have values from 0 to 100, you can change color every 10% by create a colorscale composed of 0.0, 0.1,0.2 etc..). You're free to compose it as you wish

Comment: @Basj here you can find original colorscales from Plotly, so you can also take inspiration from here: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/5bc25b490702e5ed61265207833dbd58e8ab27f1/src/components/colorscale/scales.js